# WP-PostRating Ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, admin-ajax

I have WP-PostRating Plugins for rating system, but onclick="rate_post();" onkeypress="rate_post(); function not working.

I think PostRating JS conflict with other JS, 

ERROR LOG

```
[15-May-2016 09:10:34 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `wpgc_koo` (`term` ) VALUES ( 'how to be single vidto' ) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/teangan/search.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/teangan/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, oc_setinfo, oc_save_term
[15-May-2016 09:17:29 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `wpgc_koo` (`term` ) VALUES ( 'coc cheat without offer' ) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/teangan/search.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/teangan/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, oc_setinfo, oc_save_term
[15-May-2016 09:27:41 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `wpgc_koo` (`term` ) VALUES ( 'cheat coc lewat android' ) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/teangan/search.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/teangan/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, oc_setinfo, oc_save_term
[15-May-2016 09:36:19 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `wpgc_koo` (`term` ) VALUES ( 'cheat coc online android' ) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/teangan/search.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/teangan/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, oc_setinfo, oc_save_term
[15-May-2016 09:38:02 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:04 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:06 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:10 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:12 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:13 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:14 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:26 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:38:28 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query SELECT `term` FROM `wpgc_koo` WHERE `term` != '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25000 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::DoTemplateRedirect, GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::CallShowSitemap, GoogleSitemapGenerator->ShowSitemap, do_action('sm_build_content'), call_user_func_array, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->Content, GoogleSitemapGeneratorStandardBuilder->BuildMisc, do_action('sm_buildmap'), call_user_func_array, ocim_generate_sitemap
[15-May-2016 09:39:25 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'free_wp204.wpgc_koo' doesn't exist for query INSERT IGNORE INTO `wpgc_koo` (`term` ) VALUES ( 'alka yagnik' ) made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/teangan/search.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/teangan/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, oc_setinfo, oc_save_term
```

i dont know how to solve this.

Please guide me now what should i check to work it in my favor.
my site : http://9fre.com